# Using JMeter regex extraction in a loop controller

Tags: jmeter

Right now, I have a Simple Controller set up to send a HTTP Request, and am extracting the request ID number from the response I get. This is working correctly. However, I want to send 3 such requests, and extract the request ID number from each, and may want to do even more in the future. I'm thinking the best way to set this up would be a loop controller, but I'm not sure how to extend my regex extractor that works for 1 HTTP request to work for multiple HTTP requests. The request ID number will be different each time, so I have to have a different variable for each, but I'm not sure how to make that happen. I was also looking at the ForEach loop, but I don't have any variables I am using as input, so I'm not sure that is the right choice for what I'm looking to do.

Comment: What will you do with the reqID once you capture it? Would you be able to use it within the same loop and then discard it? Do you have to save them for use later?

Comment: I need to save them all for use later, if that's possible.

Comment: So why not write the value to file each time you capture it? Why do they have to be in different variables? If you need to keep them all in-memory at run time, you can create any java collection and keep inserting the values into it.

Comment: That's definitely a smarter way to do things. I'm very new to JMeter, so it honestly never occured to me to do that. but I do remember reading about it when going through the documentation. I'll do it that way - thanks for your help!